# Passing props in Semantic UI React's dropdown component

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm new to React and am using the library: Semantic-UI-React.

I'm trying to use the Dropdown component from Semantic-UI-React but I am unable to pass my props. I get an error when I console.log my props anywhere in the example code.

The Semantic-UI-React dropdown example looks different than my normal react code. It only has an export. My normal code has a render and a return section.

http://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown

My parent page gets the child like this:

```
<div className="ui grid">
    <TagFilter handleTagChange={this.handleTagChange} tagsFilterValue={this.state.tagsFilterValue} />
</div>
```

My TagFilter component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react'

import { friendOptions } from '../common'

const DropdownExampleSelection = () => (
  <Dropdown placeholder='Select Friend' fluid selection options={friendOptions} />
)

export default DropdownExampleSelection
```

I don't know if I can rewrite the code in the example to look more like the rest of my code.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: It exports as a module, in your App.js you can import it and use it as component. Same as they import Dropdown in your example.

Comment: You have not defined any component called `TagFilter`, at least not in any provided code. It's not clear what you are trying to do.
I'd recommend you start by using react without this library until you know the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. I will assume that there is a `TagFilterComponent` and you want to render `Dropdown` components in it.**

I suggest that you create a component of your own, let's call it `TagDropdown`. You pass this the props you want and you add the functions you need. Then for its `render`-function - you use the `DropDown` components as you want them. By the code you provided

That is, [you extend the DropDown by composition](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html).

Something like:

```
class TagDropdown extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    // Add your functions and handlers, if any. 
    render() {
      return (
        <Dropdown /* <add your props and options> */ />
      )
    }
}
```

Now your `TagFilterComponent` can render a `<TagDropdown>` and you can pass the props of your choice.

Comment: Thanks Tapirboy,

When I call my function my event (e) is a proxy object. But if I add like test  in my function like this:

  `handleTagChange(test, e) {
    console.log("handleTagChange");
    console.log(e);
  }`

Then e returns the dropdown target value correctly. Why is this?

Comment: No worries, feel free to accept answer if it did help you. 
Regarding this `handleTagChange` you probably better create a new question and provide sufficient code to understand the context.

Comment: @Tapirboy I know this a weird way to reach out to you, but did you used to run TravAlert? If so, i have been trying to get in touch with you via your Blogspot site about it. Could you reach out to me when you get a chance please?